# Can we filter our own questions based on acceptance of an answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I try to keep my acceptance rate at above 90%. Is there a way to filter for questions that have not been accepted so I don't have to check every one? Seems silly but as the number of questions grows the task gets harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, I know of no way to filter out questions with an accepted answer. The fastest way is to look for the green rectangles around the number of answers:

$\hspace{6cm}$[image]

The posts with the green rectangles have an accepted answer. (I'm sorry if you already know this, it's the only way I know to look for questions with(out) accepted answers other than opening them).

**Addendum**

The answer by Martin Sleziak seems to answer your question in the affirmative. [This link](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3Ame+hasaccepted%3A0&submit=search) should show you what you want.

Comment: No actually I didn't know it so it's a big help. Thanks.

Comment: Note that on other sites, the indication might be different. For example, on Physics.SE, it is a green circle, on GameDev.SE it is a green hexagon, and on Stats.SE it is a green triangle. However, on all the sites I have seen, it is green highlight of some sort.

Comment: No offense to you robjohn, obviously a very valued member of the community, but OP, let this be a lesson in waiting a little bit to see if someone else can provide a better answer before accepting one.

Comment: @Graphth: daniel is free to accept Martin Sleziak's answer instead if he feels that it answers his question better.

Comment: Recently there was a meta.SO question about the same thing: [Indication on main question page that the question is answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149734/indication-on-main-question-page-that-the-question-is-answered)

Answer (score 10):

If you have a look at [help for advanced search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search) you will find out that [hasaccepted:1](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=hasaccepted%3a1%20) returns questions which have an accepted answer and [hasaccepted:0](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=active&q=hasaccepted%3a0%20) retuns questions which do not have an accepted answer.

You might want to sort the search results according to your preference (newest/active).

To find your own questions without an accepted answer you can search for [hasaccepted:0 user:me](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=hasaccepted%3A0+user%3Ame). (And again, you can then sort the results in the way which is suitable for you.)

Comment: Nice! I had never noticed that.

Comment: Awesome!  Because I like this answer, I will star this question.

Comment: Intresting. If only we could also avoid people who refuse to accept any answer. (accept rate 1% or less).
Although accept rates depends on the difficulty of the question accepting less than 2% is probably silly.